# Angularjs- How to close autosearch view

Tags: angularjs, view, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angularjs. I have a input box, below which I'm showing the search results. My code samples are given below. I want close the search result on clicking on "Close search result" span. But could not get any way out. Please help me out.

**Screenshot:**

[image: snapshot]

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a item..." ng-model="autoSearch" ng-keyup="getList()" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="autosearch-result">
        <div class="search-result-close-block">
            <span class="search-result-close-text">Items found :</span>
            <span class="close" title="Close search result">×</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>.....</li>
            <li>.....</li>
            <li>.....</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.autosearch-result {
position: absolute;
top: 100% !important;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: A more angular way of approaching your problem would be to watch with `scope.$watch` the `autoSearch` and have your search result be hidden if there is not `resultModel`.  **In the watcher function**: Check if there is a `autoSearch` value.  If there is a value do a search an update the `resultModel`. If autoSearch is set `resultModel` to `null` this would cause the div to hide, because `ng-show="resultModel"` would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to add a value to your scope that would have a boolean value that tracks if the span should be hidden/shown

Then you will want to use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to hide/show the div.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a item..." 
              ng-model="autoSearch" ng-keyup="getList()" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="autosearch-result" ng-show="!displayResult">
        <div class="search-result-close-block">
            <span class="search-result-close-text">Items found :</span>
            <span class="close" title="Close search result" 
                  ng-click="displayResult = false>×</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>.....</li>
            <li>.....</li>
            <li>.....</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```